# Wordpress wp_get_post_terms order by parent not ordering children and grandchildren correctly

Tags: wordpress

I think that the start of my problem is that parent children and grandchildren don't have the ID's in hierarchical order, the parent category was added after children categories so i have problem ordering them correctly.

I want to get the list of custom taxonomies for custom post type, for that i use the function `wp_get_post_terms` to list the taxonomies. But i can't get them in order of `parent` > `children` > `grandchildren`

From the wordpress documentation this should work:

`wp_get_post_terms($edit_post->ID, 'listings_category', array("fields" => "ids", "orderby" => "parent"));`

But the grandchildren category is always listed before children category.

This is the categories list:

```
Services
   -- Design
      -- Artistic
```

But in the database their id's are not hierarchical

```
Services => id(454)
Design   => id(43)
Artistic => id(44)
```

And i can't make them display in order `Services` > `Design` > `Artistic`

They always end up in different order.

Here's an array output

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(WP_Term)#7074 (10) {
    ["term_id"]=>
    int(494)
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Services"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(8) "services"
    ["term_group"]=>
    int(0)
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
    int(494)
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(17) "listings_category"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["parent"]=>
    int(0)
    ["count"]=>
    int(1)
    ["filter"]=>
    string(3) "raw"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(WP_Term)#7073 (10) {
    ["term_id"]=>
    int(44)
    ["name"]=>
    string(20) "Artistic"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(18) "artistic"
    ["term_group"]=>
    int(0)
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
    int(44)
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(17) "listings_category"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["parent"]=>
    int(43)
    ["count"]=>
    int(1)
    ["filter"]=>
    string(3) "raw"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(WP_Term)#7075 (10) {
    ["term_id"]=>
    int(43)
    ["name"]=>
    string(23) "Design"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(23) "design"
    ["term_group"]=>
    int(0)
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
    int(43)
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(17) "listings_category"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["parent"]=>
    int(494)
    ["count"]=>
    int(1)
    ["filter"]=>
    string(3) "raw"
  }
}
```

Comment: Per WP codex page it say that `ASC` is the default but anyway i tried to set it up `DESC` and `ASC` it doesn't change it to correct order just set it on reverse order.

Comment: Do you require the array to be flat? I think it could be better (depending on your use-case), when hierarchical terms are shown hierarchically. See this answer for that: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/99516/194988  
Otherwise you have to write your on function to sort the array...